# Flink in Kubernetes. How to add submit job step to jobmanager flink docker?

Tags: java, kubernetes, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I use Flink with K8s. Everything works fine, but I have to submit jar manually when jobmanager is up.

I think we can extend flink image and add post action to submit job.
So jobmanager will be one for one flink job.
I think it was the idea from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w721NI-mtAA

In this case if JM is down, K8s will up new pod and resubmit the job.

Am I right?

Does anyone have such docker changes for flink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this stuff.

I extend flink Docker and added "Flink run "some.jar"" step to it.

It works perfect

https://github.com/Aleksandr-Filichkin/flink-k8s

Comment: I tried the docker image specified in the project and i have described the issue i am facing in the following link. https://github.com/Aleksandr-Filichkin/flink-k8s/issues/1. Would be great if you could provide some pointers.

Comment: @Akshata, looks like you didn't start task-manager service/deployment, only job manager.
try kubectl create -f taskmanager-deployment.yaml

Comment: I am already running the taskmanager. I added the taskmanager logs to the ticket.

Comment: I made a change to the docker_entrypoint_custom.sh at line 54.`exec $(drop_privs_cmd) flink "$FLINK_HOME/bin/jobmanager.sh" start-foreground` to resolve the issue.